Cannot create private endpoint for Application Gateway
I'm trying to create a Private Endpoint for an Azure Application Gateway in my environment, but I keep getting the following error, although the private link exists and is in "Succeeded" state:

ERROR: (ApplicationGatewayPrivateLinkOperationError) Call to
Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways failed. Error message: Cannot
perform private link operation on ApplicationGateway
/subscriptions/26d8a9f9../resourceGroups/rg-dev-new-test5/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/app-gateway-dev.
Please make sure application gateway has private link configuration.
Code: ApplicationGatewayPrivateLinkOperationError Message: Call to
Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways failed. Error message: Cannot
perform private link operation on ApplicationGateway
/subscriptions/26d8a9f9../resourceGroups/rg-dev-new-test5/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/app-gateway-dev.
Please make sure application gateway has private link configuration.

Steps Taken:

Created a Virtual Network with a dedicated subnet for the Application Gateway.

Created a Public IP for the Application Gateway.

Created a WAF Policy and associated it with the Application Gateway.

Deployed the Application Gateway successfully with the WAF_v2 SKU.

Attempted to create a Private Endpoint.


Below there is a standalone bash script that demonstrates the problem
#!/bin/bash
set -e
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

# Configurations
LOCATION="westeurope"
RG="rg-dev-new-test5"
VNET="vnet-ai-services-dev"
ADDR="10.0.0.0/16"
APPGW_SUBNET="app-gateway-subnet-dev"
APPGW_PREFIX="10.0.2.0/24"
PE_SUBNET="private-endpoint-subnet-dev"
PE_PREFIX="10.0.9.0/24"
APPGW="app-gateway-dev"
WAF="waf-policy-dev"
PIP="appgw-public-ip"
PRIVATE_LINK_CONFIG="appgw-private-link-config"
SUB_ID=$(az account show --query id -o tsv)

# Create Resource Group
az group create -n $RG -l $LOCATION

# Create Virtual Network with Application Gateway subnet
az network vnet create -g $RG -n $VNET --address-prefix $ADDR \
  --subnet-name $APPGW_SUBNET --subnet-prefix $APPGW_PREFIX

# Create Private Endpoint subnet
az network vnet subnet create -g $RG --vnet-name $VNET -n $PE_SUBNET \
  --address-prefixes $PE_PREFIX --disable-private-link-service-network-policies true

# Create Public IP for Application Gateway
az network public-ip create -g $RG -n $PIP --sku Standard --allocation-method Static

# Create WAF Policy
az network application-gateway waf-policy create -g $RG -n $WAF -l $LOCATION

# Construct WAF Policy ID
WAF_ID="/subscriptions/$SUB_ID/resourceGroups/$RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/$WAF"

# Create Application Gateway with WAF_v2 SKU and Priority
az network application-gateway create -n $APPGW -g $RG -l $LOCATION \
  --capacity 2 --sku WAF_v2 --vnet-name $VNET --subnet $APPGW_SUBNET \
  --public-ip-address $PIP --frontend-port 80 --http-settings-port 80 \
  --http-settings-protocol Http --routing-rule-type Basic --waf-policy $WAF_ID \
  --priority 100

# Get Application Gateway Frontend IP Configuration Name
FRONTEND_IP_NAME=$(az network application-gateway frontend-ip list  --gateway-name $APPGW --resource-group $RG  --query "[0].name"  -o tsv)

# Add Private Link Configuration to Application Gateway
az network application-gateway private-link add \
  --resource-group $RG \
  --gateway-name $APPGW \
  --name $PRIVATE_LINK_CONFIG \
  --frontend-ip $FRONTEND_IP_NAME \
  --subnet "/subscriptions/$SUB_ID/resourceGroups/$RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$VNET/subnets/$PE_SUBNET"

# Get Private Link Configuration ID
PRIVATE_LINK_CONFIG_ID=$(az network application-gateway private-link show \
  --resource-group $RG \
  --gateway-name $APPGW \
  --name $PRIVATE_LINK_CONFIG \
  --query id -o tsv)

# Get Application Gateway ID
APPGW_ID=$(az network application-gateway show -n $APPGW -g $RG --query id -o tsv)

# Attempt to create Private Endpoint (expected to succeed if supported)
az network private-endpoint create -n "appgw-pe" -g $RG --vnet-name $VNET \
  --subnet $PE_SUBNET \
  --private-connection-resource-id $APPGW_ID \
  --group-id "gateway" \
  --connection-name "appgw-pec" \
  --location $LOCATION

What part of the code needs adjustment so that the private-endpoint create command can recognize the private link?

Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways failed. Error message: Cannot perform private link operation on ApplicationGateway /subscriptions/26d8a9f9../resourceGroups/rg-dev-newtest5/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/app-gateway-dev. Please make sure application gateway has private link configuration.

The error above was encountered due to invalid values passed in the command az network private-endpoint create.
When I passed the invalid values in the command, I encountered the same error as you.

To resolve the issue, make sure to pass the correct values. The Group ID should be the Frontend IPConfiguration name, and the connection name should be the Private Link Configurations name.

Here is the updated script for creating a private endpoint for the application gateway.
$subnetupdate= az network vnet subnet update --name "APP-Subnet2" --vnet-name "App-Vnet" --resource-group "application-RG" --disable-private-link-service-network-policies true
$appgateway = az network application-gateway frontend-ip list --gateway-name "Venkat-app-gateway" --resource-group "application-RG"
$appgatewayJson = $appgateway | ConvertFrom-Json
$groupid = $appgatewayJson[0].name

$appgatewayID = az network application-gateway show -n "Venkat-app-gateway" -g "application-RG" --query id -o tsv

$privatelink = az network application-gateway private-link add --frontend-ip "appGwPublicFrontendIpIPv4" --name "privateLinkConfig01" --subnet "/subscriptions/8332bf56-aa7c-4daa-a507-d7e60e5f09a9/resourceGroups/application-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/App-Vnet/subnets/App-subnet" --gateway-name "Venkat-app-gateway" --resource-group "application-RG"

$privatelink = az network application-gateway private-link list --gateway-name "Venkat-app-gateway" --resource-group "application-RG"
$appprivatelinkJson = $privatelink | ConvertFrom-Json
$frontendipconfiguration = $appprivatelinkJson[0].name

az network private-endpoint create --name "AppGWPrivateEndpoint2" --resource-group "application-RG" --vnet-name "App-Vnet" --subnet "APP-Subnet2" --group-id $groupid --private-connection-resource-id $appgatewayID --connection-name $frontendipconfiguration

Output:

Reference: Configure Azure Application Gateway Private Link
